# Tracking user id from cookie with Google tag manager

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, userid

I am trying to write my user ID to cookie. I can catch it from `dataLayer` variable from server when user is login in but user can be already logged in next session. So I tried to create custom JavaScript code that suppose to check if variable is not undefined and write a cookie and if the cookie exist then returns cookie value.

```
function() {
    if ({{UID dataLayer}}) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 2);
        var expiresdate = 'Expires=' + d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = 'UIDcookie=' + {{UID dataLayer}} + '; ' + expiresdate + '; Path=/';
        return {{UID dataLayer}};
    } else if ({{UID Cookie}}) {
        return {{UID Cookie}};
    }
    return;
}
```

But it works only when I'm in `tagmanager` debug mode, when it's off nothing suppose to happen. So my question is what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Quick question. Can you confirm the GTM is being published?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a question of timing. Try to fire the tag to the page load, in this way the function in JS variable should be able to read the cookie.